# Why does 'go vet' complain only in some versions of Go?

Tags: go

Today I included 'go vet' in one of my pipelines that builds a go service. I wonder why `go vet`'s output on my local machine is different from the one that runs on the CI server.

I figured out that the go version differs - at least a bit. My local Go version is 1.12.4 and the CIs is version 1.12.7. This fact would explain the different behaviour, but I don't get why this happens!

There is the smell:

```
type Something struct {
    ...
    BatteryNumber string    `json:"number"`
    ...
}

type SomethingWithBattery struct {
    Something
    Number            string   `json:"number"`
    ...
}
```

So, two times 'number' in the struct tags, because Something-struct is nested SomethingWithBattery -  1.12.4 complains, 1.12.7 does not. Why?

Comment: This issue was fixed in 1.12.5: https://golang.org/issue/30465

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [Go 1 and the Future of Go Programs](https://golang.org/doc/go1compat)
>
> [Tools](https://golang.org/doc/go1compat#tools)
>
> Finally, the Go toolchain (compilers, linkers, build tools, and so on)
>   is under active development and may change behavior. This means, for
>   instance, that scripts that depend on the location and properties of
>   the tools may be broken by a point release.

---

`go vet` is under active development and recently it has been rewritten. There is no compatibility guarantee for tools, only the language.

---

> [cmd/vet: Consider reverting tag conflict for embedded fields #30465](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/30465)
>
> go vet fails due to intended shadowing of embedded fields with json
>   tags.

---

Also, bug fixes are applied to the Go tools. For example, [Issue 30465](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/30465).